# upgrade from ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 18.04 failed

Tags: upgrade

my ubuntu 16 just completed a routine adjustment of its system files like it often does.  it keeps asking me to upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 so i finally gave it permission to do so.  this process took over ten hours then it finished with a report that the upgrade had failed.  it had been saying that 'systemd' was reporting errors, but it returned me to my usual ubuntu 16 desktop.  i started doing a file transfer which i commonly do but the usb drive would not connect.  when i tried a reboot, it came up with the red beaver ubuntu 18.04 log on screen with my name in the password entry box, but it fails to accept my password.  whenever i put in the password, the screen goes black then the drum error sound plays and it returns to the password entry on the red beaver screen.  i can not get anything other than the beaver password entry panel.

i have a complete ubuntu 18.04 set of CD disks which i have used on another computer.  can i use it to repair whatever has been lost in this failed upgrade?  i do not want to lose all of my data on the harddrive which was created there under under version 16, but this upgrade seems to have lost my password somehow.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16?    Are you trying to convert Ubuntu Core 16 into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? as that isn't a supported move.  There is Ubuntu 16, as server & desktop releases use *yy.mm* format, and only special purposes releases like Ubuntu Core 16 for IoT appliances use the *yy* format; whilst based on server releases they aren't identical.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once - you could try this:

the .gnome file in your home directory could be corrupt. Rename it to something else (.gnome-old) by opening a terminal at login (ctrl alt f2) or by booting off a usb image.  Then reboot normally.